# how to customize a loss function with an extra variable in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I want to train a model with a self-customized loss function. The loss includes two parts. Part1 and part2 can be calculated with y_true (labels) and y_predicted (real output). 
However, the `loss = part1 +lambda part2`

The lambda is a variable that should be able to adjust together with the parameters of the network model. In tensorflow, it seems the lambda can be defined as tf.Variable to updated. However, how can I do it in Keras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have come up with a solution. It is ugly, but it's a solution:

```
class UtilityLayer(Layer):

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            name='kernel',
            shape=(1,),
            initializer='ones',
            trainable=True,
            constraint='nonneg'
        )
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.kernel


switch = -1
last_loss = 0

def custom_loss_builder(utility_layer):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        global switch, last_loss
        switch *= -1

        if switch == 1:
            last_loss = utility_layer.trainable_weights[0] * MSE(y_true, y_pred) 
            return last_loss # your network loss
        else:
            return last_loss # your lambda loss

    return custom_loss


dummy_y = np.empty(len(x))

inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(2, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = Dense(1)(x)
utility_outputs = UtilityLayer()(inputs)

model = Model(inputs, [outputs, utility_outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss_builder(model.layers[-1]))
model.fit(x, [y, dummy_y], epochs=100)
```

And the evolution of your lambda:

[image: chart]

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have a question. In that case, we changed the output of the model from y to [y, dumy_y]. Then, does the y_true, and y_pred also changed? So we need to specify y_true = y_true[0] and y_pred = y_pred[0]?

Comment: Hello, in that case, your `model.predict(x_test) = [y_pred, y_dummy]`, so you want to access `model.predict(x_test)[0]`. I'm not sure what your `y_true` is though, if it is your original `y_train`, you don't need to access the first element, but you could also define `y_true = [y_train, y_dummy]`, it's up to you.